# ¿para que se utiliza myclassrepository en este codigo de un controlador de symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

hola he hecho un pequeño programa en symfony para mostrar los datos de una base de datos en una tabla. Me guie por un tutorial que encontre en internet pero no se muy bien como funciona. Mi duda es para que sirve el myClassRepository en este codigo (que parece ser el que le pasa a la vista los datos de la base de datos). Este es el controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Usuarios;
use App\Repository\MyClassRepository;
/**
    * @Route("/usuarios")
    */

class NombreControladorController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
    * @Route("/", name="usuarios")
    */
    public function index(MyClassRepository $myClassRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('nombre_controlador/index.html.twig', ['usuarios' => $myClassRepository->findAll(),]);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino estés utilizando sf 4.4, 5 o 6. La filosofía del framework no ha cambiado mucho entre estas versiones pero abogan por desacoplar más las clases, hacer más uso de la inyección de dependencias y pasar la lógica de tus controladores hacia clases de servicio; es decir que miremos a los controllers como lo que realmente son unos facilitadores (por buscarle un término) entre la vista, la lógica de negocio y tu modelo; **y aprovechando que tus repositories están dispoibles como servicios, entonces los puedes pasar como parámetro de tu action** en resumen.